# Drive image only partitioned space

Tags: linux, debian, backup

I have a 32GB drive (SD card) with 4 partitions. Total partitioned space is <2GB.

I need to make an *.img file so that I can clone it to other SD cards which are smaller than 32GB.

If I just use "dd" I get an image file that is the full size of the card - 32GB.

This is all under Linux and the SD card is bootable, so can't just copy files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "dd" for each partition (need to get their start blocks and active sizes, you may use fdisk for that). Also you need to use "dd" to get boot sector. Then you can create partition table with 4 partitions on second SD card and copy 4 partition images there using "dd" and information on start blocks and sizes for this SD. Also you need to "dd" boot sector.